# dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'onlyoffice-documentserver' missing

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

dpkg warning does not go.  tried apt update/upgrade/autoremove/autoclean/purge.
tried fix broken packages in synaptic also.
this happened when i tried to install onlyoffice and then installation failed with some errors which i did not note.

```
gmk@Pavilion:~$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed and 0 not upgraded. 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'onlyoffice-documentserver' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 519885 files and directories currently installed.)
```